# Edit Field Value of Feature Class Using Python in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table

I have a feature class whose attribute table looks like this:

Latitude | Longitude  | Area

For the area column, all rows are null.  I would like to put in a specific value for all rows using Python.

I know how to do this on the front-end in the ArcMaps application ( right click > Open Attribute Table > right click on column > field calculator > input value).

How can I accomplish this programmatically using Python?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the area for each feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way, until you are more familiar with the syntax, would be to use the field calculator as you normally do and then go to `Geoprocessing -> Results`. From there, you can expand `Current Session` and, right-clicking on the most recent tool that was run, select `Copy as Python Snippet`.

You'll likely have to change the names of a few inputs, but that should get you started.

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the values for a column with Python by using either a GP tool [Calculate Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000) or arcpy [UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) (this one is faster when working with large datasets).

For calculating the geometrical properties of features, you can either use GP tool [Add Geometry Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000191000000) or using tokens (such as [SHAPE@AREA](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001t000000)) of update cursor.

Comment: +1 for cursors, specifically the data access module. I don't really use Calculate Field anymore.

Comment: @Paul, I still do :) sometimes it is just plain easier syntax wise. Of course only for minor datasets.

Comment: Anything past one or two lines, yes. :)